# System.out is not recognised

Tags: java, netbeans, package, system.out

This is driving me absolutely crazy. I have a package that was working fine, then I renamed the package and now I cannot use `System.out` (or anything in the `System` class). For what it's worth here is my `Main` class (I've removed EVERYTHING except the `System.out` line just in case something else was causing the issue).

```
package goldminetosugarconvertor;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("prog init");
    }
}
```

In NetBeans the `out` in `System.out.println` is underlined with an error `"cannot find symbol"` but the weird thing is it shows the location as "class `goldminetosugarconvertor.System`" which is obviously wrong.

Any bright ideas? I am guessing that something got broken when I renamed the package but I just can't figure out what would break so bad that `System` was not recognised.

Comment: did you let the ide perform the renaming of the package?

Comment: Well, the obvious question is: do you have a class named System in package `goldminetosugarconvertor`?

Comment: try closing alle files and project then IDE, then restart and load the project again.

Comment: did you perform a clean / rebuild already? Bugs happen, even in IDE's but normally cleaning the project should get rid of the problem. I presume you don't have a System class in your pacakge?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must have a `System` class in the package `goldminetosugarconvertor`. When you changed whatever the old package `Main` was apart of to this one, you've now shadowed `System` from `java.lang` with `goldminetosugarconvertor.System`.

Unless you remove this `System` class, you'll have to prepend `System.out` with `java.lang.`, ie:

```
java.lang.System.out.println("prog init");
```

Comment: YES!! That was it! Thanks for the swift response everyone. lack of sleep strikes again :)

Comment: @takesides: If I were you, I'd probably avoid naming my classes the same as the ones in the Java library, or at least common ones like `System`.

Comment: Don't forget to accept AusCBloke's answer. He nailed this one for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem today as the person that originally posed the question. Eclipse would not recognize System.out.println in my new class or any other that I created (except it would in an older class in the same package), very strange!

Didn't already have a (second) System class.

Restarted Eclipse, didn't help.

Restarted my PC, didn't help.

Fixed the problem by creating a new class called 'String' .. I'm surprised that Eclipse didn't warn me! Anyway I deleted that new class and hey presto ! I can type System.out.println in all my classes - no problem!

Hope this helps someone else too !

Comment: Clearing the project cache and rebuilding the project should work as well.

Comment: I have had this problem when i declare interface withh name "System"